# Postfix address remapping

Tags: postfix, sendmail

My website contains a form (contact us) that send an email (WordPress via Ninjaforms).
I've configured both ninja-form and postfix to send the email from myname@e-levelcom.com
However it keeps sending as www-data@www.e-levelcom.com and it is blocked by gmail as spam.

For postfix, I followed many guides on the web and all of them leads to this:

- in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` I have appended `smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic`
- then created `/etc/postfix/generic` and added `www-data@www.e-levelcom.com myname@e-levelcom.com`
- then run `postmap /etc/postfix/generic` and restarted postfix service

However, if I look into `/var/log/mail.log` the from address is still www-data@www.e-levelcom.com

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: replace `www-data@www.e-levelcom.com` with just `www-data` in `/etc/postfix/generic` and run `postmap /etc/postfix/generic` to compile and reload postfix.

Comment: @arzyfex: unfortunately that doesn't work

Comment: Did you clean out the mail-queue after changing the parameter? (postqueue) ... Maybe there are some old mails in the queue. The configuration is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix this with postfix, so I decided to remove postfix and install sendmail instead. This is the guide how to configure sendmail to mask sender:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Sendmail-Address-Rewrite-3.html

For 3.1 I only needed to include

```
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope) FEATURE(genericstable, `hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable')
GENERICS_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/genericsdomain')
```

and then 3.2 is where the trick is.

Don't forget to restart `sendmail` service at the end.